# How to use an apostrophe in a Salesforce HTML email template body

Tags: email, html, template

I added an apostrophe to an HTML Email Template and it didn't render in the test email. I'm trying to write: "I'm".

I tried `&#39;`, but that showed up as is.

How do I type an apostrophe in email templates?

Thanks!

Comment: Which type of template? Standard HTML or Custom HTML? That actually makes a difference here.

Comment: I am using a Custom HTML email template.